# Why is a static variable of constant class not concatenating value set from other class?

Tags: java, android

Hi I have a Constant class in which there is a base url

```
public static String BASE_URL = "";
```

I am assigning this value from my login activity

```
URLsAndConstants.BASE_URL += enterUrlEditText.getText().toString();
```

And then I am doing this in my Constant class again

```
public  static String AUTHENTICATE_USER_BY_AD = BASE_URL + "/MyApi";
```

While I can log the value of BASE_URL after assigning , I cannot append it to the other static string ie 
when I use this `public  static String AUTHENTICATE_USER_BY_AD`
in API it does not concatenate the value of BASE_URL. What am I doing wrong and what do I need to do ?

Comment: Please show us the class, if it is huge, just show the related parts.

Comment: You can put breakpoints on these lines to see the order they run.

Comment: @deHaar Actually the reason is static variables are getting intiialized earlier

Comment: I appreciate the quick accept!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Static constants get (typically) assigned their values right when the class is loaded.

In other words: Constants class gets loaded, and BASE_URL gets "".

**Next** AUTHENTICATE_USER_BY_AD gets assigned the result of that expression `"" + ...;`, based on the *current* value of the static field.

The fact that **later** BASE_URL gets re-assigned doesn't lead to AUTHENTICATE_USER_BY_AD being "re-computed". That one sticks with the initial value!

The "real" answer here: don't use static fields like that. If at all, you could create a method

```
String getAuthenticatedUserUrl() {
  return BASE_URL + "/MyApi";
}
```

to then invoke that method. But as said: already the idea of *updating* that static field **after** the facts is a bad idea. That totally breaks for example as soon as you have multiple threads, and different ways to set that field!

The *real* solution could be to have a "some sort" of Url class. When creating an instance of that class, you define the `baseUrl` for that single instance.

Comment: Thank you a lot :)

Comment: here are the answers appear correct and it would be unjust to accept only one :)

Comment: Answers always have different qualities. You the one that you find most helpful, . If they are really "all equal" (which I doubt) you could simply pick the first. Beyond that, keep in mind: accepting an answer helps future readers. They immediately see "this one works", instead of being left with 5 similar answers, but "hey, did they really help"? Not accepting an answer sends a message, too!

Answer (score 1):

From your code snippet, `BASE_URL` and `AUTHENTICATE_USER_BY_AD` are evaluated as soon as your Constant class is loaded up (before your login activity). 
Any further changes to the `BASE_URL` in your activity will not change the value of `AUTHENTICATE_USER_BY_AD`.

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are doing nothing:

The line:

```
public static String AUTHENTICATE_USER_BY_AD = BASE_URL + "/MyApi";
```

Is only called once when your app is loaded and initializes `AUTHENTICATE_USER_BY_AD` with whatever value is in `BASE_URL` at that time.

It does not create any link between `AUTHENTICATE_USER_BY_AD` and `BASE_URL` variables.

You will need to add code to keep both variables updated together.

This is why it is not recommended to use public members in classes, and instead use [getters and setters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutator_method).

This goes for any non `final` (constant) static members as well.

In your case, you would want to create a `public static setBaseUrl(String url)` function that will make all the changes involved in updating the base URL of your app and make `BASE_URL` it self private.

Answer (score 1):

The problem lies in `static` keyword in

```
public  static String AUTHENTICATE_USER_BY_AD = BASE_URL + "/MyApi";
```

It being `static`, it gets first loaded at the same time with

```
public static String BASE_URL = "";
```

It means there won't be any effect on **AUTHENTICATE_USER_BY_AD** no matter how you change your **BASE_URL**.

In your case, a `static` method might be a solution:

```
public static String getApiURL() {

    return AUTHENTICATE_USER_BY_AD = BASE_URL + "/MyApi";
}
```